# Using libraries with SAS University Edition

Tags: sas

I'm starting with SAS using SAS University Edition, and I'm trying to create a new folder. The code that I'm using is:

`libname bee 'C:\JL\B'; run;`

It gives me the note: "Library bee does not exist".

And when I try to see what is in the library using the code `proc contents data = INNOVA._all_; run;`, it gives me the error: "Library BEE does not exist" even though the word bee appears as recommended by SAS Studio when I am writing it.

Does anyone know the answer? I am using the SAS Studio of SAS University Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know about SAS University Edition, it runs inside of a Virtual Machine on your computer. Think of the Virtual Machine as an independent virtual computer. It might not have a C:\JL\B folder on it. So, I would try to figure out if you can setup the virtual machine to map to certain folders and drives on your computer before trying it.